# How can I save a julia set image as png in Python?

Tags: python

[This link to mpi documentation saves a Julia set as .pgm](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mpi4py.futures.html)

Is there any way to alter this code to save the image as .png file?

```
from mpi4py.futures import MPIPoolExecutor

x0, x1, w = -2.0, +2.0, 640*2
y0, y1, h = -1.5, +1.5, 480*2
dx = (x1 - x0) / w
dy = (y1 - y0) / h

c = complex(0, 0.65)

def julia(x, y):
    z = complex(x, y)
    n = 255
    while abs(z) < 3 and n > 1:
        z = z**2 + c
        n -= 1
    return n

def julia_line(k):
    line = bytearray(w)
    y = y1 - k * dy
    for j in range(w):
        x = x0 + j * dx
        line[j] = julia(x, y)
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with MPIPoolExecutor() as executor:
        image = executor.map(julia_line, range(h))
        with open('julia.pgm', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(b'P5 %d %d %d\n' % (w, h, 255))
            for line in image:
                f.write(line)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, add: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Get rid of everything below the line `image = executor.map(...)` and replace it with:

`plt.imsave("julia.png", image)`

I'm pretty sure that'll do ya, but beware I haven't run your code!

**UPDATE**

OK, so I had a closer look at the code and I am guessing that the 'image' variable is a tuple of bytearrays representing each line in the image. Try:

```
image = np.array([list(l) for l in image])
```

just before the plt.imsave(...) line. This converts each bytearray to a list and then packs these into an outer list. You will now also need to `import numpy as np` as I believe this is needed to convert the nested lists into a nice ndarray that matplotlib can save.

Comment: n. b. you will need to have matplotlib installed! [plt.imsave documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) and [installing matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'`